# How to tell when a shared file has been consumed by the shared app in android

Tags: android

In my application, I am sharing images using the `Intent.createChooser()` mechanism. The images, as displayed on the device, are not in their best resolution and prior to sharing, my app fetches the full resolution images from the server. The file paths to these full resolution images are sent to the shared app. When sharing is done, I want to delete these images. But when the sharing application returns control to my application via `onActivityResult()`, which is where I delete the full resolution files, some applications (gmail, yahoo mail, fb messenger) have already consumed these files, whereas others (android mail, fb) have not, and it becomes a race condition between my code deleting these files and FB fetching these files for upload. And 9 out of 10, FB upload fails. When I do not delete these files, FP upload is always successful. Since these are temporary files, I do need to delete them or the storage will eventually become full.

I thought about using my app's cache space, which is automatically cleaned up by the OS on as needed basis, but the app's cache is not accessible to the external applications; thus, the sharing fails.

How do I handle this issue?

Thank You,
Gary

Comment: Just delete them the next day. Look at the filetime.